# Delay between dynamic posts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have this JS code that is meant to display each dynamically loaded posts when clicked on:

```
    function showPost(id) {
    $.getJSON('http://hopeofgloryinternational.com/?json=get_post&post_id=' + id + '&callback=?', function(data) {
        var output='';
        output += '<h3>' + data.post.title + '</h3>';
        output += data.post.content;
        $('#mypost').html(output);
    }); //get JSON Data for Stories
} //showPost
```

When I test the page 'http://howtodeployit.com/devotion/' on my mobile or windows browser, clicked on **Daily Devotional Messages** and I navigate between each posts, I notice the previously accessed post still shows for few seconds before the new post gets displayed.

How do refresh the page or DOM so it clears out previously accessed page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

function start with a line `$('#mypost').html("");` before going to another request to clear display content.

Also you can add a waiting message `$('#mypost').html("Please wait...");` before showing content from next request.

```
function showPost(id) {

    $('#mypost').html(""); //add this line

    //$('#mypost').html("Please wait..."); //also you can add it to show waiting message.

    $.getJSON('http://hopeofgloryinternational.com/?json=get_post&post_id=' + id + '&callback=?', function(data) {
        var output='';
        output += '<h3>' + data.post.title + '</h3>';
        output += data.post.content;
        $('#mypost').html(output);
    }); //get JSON Data for Stories

}
```

Comment: Like the message bit which makes it look more professional. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Just `empty()` the contents of myPost while clicked on the item or on click of back button. Reason is that your previous content is still there in the `mypost` div, and your content page becomes visible even before the ajax call is executed which may take some time to complete say 700ms, so you will see the old content for that much period of time.

```
function showPost(id) {

 var $myPost = $('#mypost').empty(); //emtpy it

 $.getJSON('http://hopeofgloryinternational.com/?json=get_post&post_id=' + id + '&callback=?', function(data) {
    var output='';
    output += '<h3>' + data.post.title + '</h3>';
    output += data.post.content;
    $myPost.html(output);
}); //get JSON Data for Stories
```

Answer (score 0):

You can empty() $mypost

```
 var $myPost = $('#mypost').empty();
```